# how to convert ado.net to lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda, ado.net

```
select tafsil, 
       SHtafsili, 
       SH_projeh, 
       sum(bed) as sumbed, 
       sum(bes) as sumbes, 
       sum(bed) - sum(bes) as sumbedbes, 
       sum(bes) - sum(bed) as sumbesbed 
from SANAD 
where tafsil > 0 group by tafsil, SHtafsili,SH_projeh HAVING sum(bed) > sum(bes)
```

I want to convert this code from ado.net to lambda. Thank you for your help

Comment: firstly, that wouldn't be a lambda - it would be a LINQ query expression (which involves multiple lambdas), but - question: *why* do you want to take perfectly working, direct SQL code, and add multiple levels of indirection and abstraction (and room for bugs)?

Comment: `and and group by` ???

Comment: How should I direct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a LINQ provider that is giving you an `IQueryable<Sumbedbes>` or similar, then - something *like*:

```cs
var query = from row in source
            where row.tafsil > 0
            group row by new { row.tafsil, row.SHtafsili, row.SH_projeh }
            into grp
            where grp.Sum(g => g.bed) > grp.Sum(g => g.bes)
            select new
            {
                grp.Key.tafsil,
                grp.Key.SHtafsili,
                grp.Key.SH_projeh,
                sumbed = grp.Sum(g => g.bed),
                sumbes = grp.Sum(g => g.bes),
                sumbedbes = grp.Sum(g => g.bed) - grp.Sum(g => g.bes),
                sumbesbed = grp.Sum(g => g.bes) - grp.Sum(g => g.bed),
            };
```

You *may* be able to use `let`, but it depends on the query provider:

```cs
var query = from row in source
            where row.tafsil > 0
            group row by new { row.tafsil, row.SHtafsili, row.SH_projeh }
            into grp
            let sumbed = grp.Sum(g => g.bed)
            let sumbes = grp.Sum(g => g.bes)
            where sumbed  > sumbes
            select new
            {
                grp.Key.tafsil,
                grp.Key.SHtafsili,
                grp.Key.SH_projeh,
                sumbed,
                sumbes,
                sumbedbes = sumbed - sumbes,
                sumbesbed = sumbes - sumbed,
            };
```

(and frankly, the last two columns are entirely redundant)

However, and I cannot stress this enough: I'd just use the SQL you already have. It is zero risk, **much** more efficient, and you don't need to ask what query will be generated. With a tool like "Dapper", it is trivial to query simply using your existing sql:

```cs
var data = conn.Query<TheShape>(@"
select tafsil, SHtafsili, SH_projeh, sum(bed) as sumbed, sum(bes) as sumbes,
    sum(bed) - sum(bes) as sumbedbes, sum(bes) - sum(bed) as sumbesbed
from SANAD where tafsil > 0
group by tafsil, SHtafsili,SH_projeh
HAVING sum(bed) > sum(bes)").AsList();
```

where `TheShape` is just a type with matching property definitions to the returned data.

Comment: sorry for again. but I have a problem in using code
public IQueryable<SANAD> Select()
        {
            try
            {
                var query =from....
                return  query
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
and  It can't be return  query.
and this error is shown:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: int? tafsil, string SHtafsili, string SH_projeh, long? sumbed, long? sumbes, long? sumbedbes, long? sumbesbed>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SANAD>'

Comment: public IQueryable<novin.Models.DomainModels.SANAD> Select()
        {
            try
            {
                var query = from ...
                return  query
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
sorry.It can't be return query

Comment: @حسینعلیزاده nothing you've just mentioned is in the question - I'm not psychic: please edit the question to give me enough context (types, methods, etc) to comment on that